# Facebook SDK login to App Engine from iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, google-app-engine

Is the following the right way to go, to login to a backend running App Engine(Could be any) with a Facebook account.

Scenario one:

1. Login to facebook
2. Get the token from the Facebook SDK (how do you get the token?)
3. Use the Facebook token to send to the backend server
4. On the backend, use the token send from the client to verofy the user on Facebook
5. If **4** is a valid user, then create the user on the backend with username and token.
6. Any further communication with the backend - the backend could then validate the user just on the backend with the user and token created on the backend.

At sone point, I thought of doing the following:

1. Login to Facebook
2. Have facebook redirect information to the backend
3. Have the backend create user from any Facebook information
4. Let the facebook login process return to the client/ios
5. Then the user should use this token and user information to login to the backend.

Hope it make sense.